# Is there a good tutorial for implementing a facebook login into an ios app using storyboards?

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa, facebook-apps

hey guys i am trying to implement a facbook login into an ios app using storyboards.
The official facebook tutorial for authentication just uses xib files.
There is an example app out there which is using storyboards, but it is to complex to understand imao.
[over here -->](https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-social-cafe)

Is there a complete step by step guide for implementing a facebook login using storyboards out there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know for storyboards. but here's a tutorial from raywenderlich.com http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

and here more tutorials:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

We have a sample app for v3 of the Facebook SDK for iOS in GitHub: https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-social-cafe - this demonstrates how to use the Facebook SDK in conjunction with storyboards.

(PS: it's easy)

Comment: I read through it , but there is so much code around it. I really need a simple step by step tutorial for setting things up. :/

Comment: The link is dead. Could you update one that works?